# pd.DataFrame.boxplot not compatible with pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sample = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], "b":np.random.uniform(0,1,9)})

sample.boxplot(column="b", by=pd.cut(sample.a, bins=2))
```

[image: plot]

Apart from the box plot picture, some text appears around the plot. How can I remove the text from the plot?

Answer (score 5):

You can try create new column `c` by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), because in [`DataFrame.boxplot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) parameter `by` can be column:

> by : **string** or **sequence**
>
> Column in the DataFrame to group by

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], "b":np.random.uniform(0,1,9)})

sample['c'] = pd.cut(sample.a, bins=2)
sample.boxplot(column="b", by='c')
```

[image]